# Show and Download a text file with Extension

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, c#-4.0

I want to read a log file(txt file) and view this in txt file and save with txt format.
This is my code,which is working fine for showing and downloading the read content in txt file,i have few issues in that..

```
public FileResult Download(string id)
    {
        int rowId = Convert.ToInt32(id);
        LoadFileInfoCache();
        var fileDetails = from ff in _currentFileDetails
                          where ff.FileId == rowId
                          select new
                          {
                              name = ff.FileName,
                              location = ff.FileLocation
                          };
        var fileDetailsList = fileDetails.ToList();
        string fileLocation = fileDetailsList[0].location;
        string fileName = fileDetailsList[0].name;            
        string contentType = "application/txt";
        var file = System.IO.File.Open(fileLocation, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.ReadWrite);
        var stream = (Stream)(file);
        return File(stream, contentType, fileName);
    }
```

when i click save button, in save as window i want filename with extension.but it shows   only filename for me.
  and also in textfile the header name should be filename.txt but it it shows Filename[1] for my code.
can anyone please give some idea to show Filename with extn in header and save as window.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Updated code**

```
public FileResult FileOutput()
            {
                string filename = "alokdida.txt";
                string filepath = "C:\\logs\\Structured_Exception_Log.txt";

                return File(filepath, "application/octet-stream", filename);
            }
```

This should work for you.

***2nd time edit (see changed code in bold font)***

```
public FileResult Download(string id)
    {
        int rowId = Convert.ToInt32(id);
        LoadFileInfoCache();
        var fileDetails = from ff in _currentFileDetails
                          where ff.FileId == rowId
                          select new
                          {
                              name = ff.FileName,
                              location = ff.FileLocation
                          };
        var fileDetailsList = fileDetails.ToList();
        string fileLocation = fileDetailsList[0].location;
        string fileName = fileDetailsList[0].name+".txt"; // Here you need to append the .txt
        string contentType = "application/txt";
        var file = System.IO.File.Open(fileLocation, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.ReadWrite);
        var stream = (Stream)(file);
        return File(stream, contentType, fileName);
    }
```

Comment: Thanks,i have some question from this,it working fine but already my fileName have the extn like profiler.txt,if again concat .txt means in FileDownload window Filename: profiler.txt.txt but header and save As window looks fine like profiler.txt??

Comment: @AshokS . As per your code your only taking file name (fileDetailsList[0].name -- this will return only file name from the profiler.txt). Please vote and mark it as an answer if its resolved your query